# What voip providers are available in Canada and why do you recommend them?

Tags: voip

I am about to go to a voip only solution for my telephone needs. What voip providers are available in Canada?

Why do you recommend them?

Comment: This is where community wiki comes in. You're looking for discussion (which this site is not) and a poll (which definitely warrants c-wiki mode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have selected VBuzzer.

They are inexpensive and provided me with a 416 number and a very inexpensive plan.

If someone else doesn't give me an answer in a few days, I will have to select my own answer.

C'mon.